# How to effectively debug method chained function arguments?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

Have a look at the following code structure:

```
myFunction(
  _(myArray)
    .filter({ keep: true })
    .uniq('id')
    .value()
);
```

`myFunction()` takes as its argument the result of some array transformation using lodash. While I like the style of the code, I find it hard to debug and end up refactoring it to have the lodash code inside another function or assign it to a variable first, then pass the variable to `myFunction()`.

Do you know of an effective way to debug the function argument code without refactoring? Some thoughts:

- As is, one cannot add `console.log`'s right in place.
- In Chrome DevTools it's not possible to set a breakpoint e.g. between `.filter()` and `.uniq()`

Comment: My thoughts: If a task is complex enough to require debugging, then extract to a separate function, pass it into the chain, and set a debug point there. You can also use `.tap` to just print out what's in there right now. However the thing presented here looks completely fine - as long as the input data conforms to the expectation, the chain will work, so there is no need to debug _that_ just look at what is coming in.

Comment: Chained code like this is not easy to debug. I usually keep each step a local until I got them right. Then once I got the desired output assemble the chain and ideally factor it out in a function. If you can't touch the code even while debugging, that's tough luck...

Comment: I wanted to add - what I said is true for lodash - if you have code that supports fluent interface and you want to debug that sort of chain...then I'd suggest not using a fluent interface. Unless your code is as simple in concept and as tested lodash's. If you are chaining relatively simple functions (e.g. array -> map -> filter -> map -> reduce) with trivial callbacks in each, then that shouldn't really require huge effort in debugging.

Comment: thanks for your comments! @vlaz I forgot about `.tap()`, something like `.tap(function(array) { debugger; })` works great (I don't mind adding the line like a console.log, I just don't want to rearrange the whole section whenever I need to find out something). And I agree with your last comment: If I was method-chaining my own code, I'd probably just set breakpoints in my own code inside the function calls.

Comment: I usually just break before the statement, and copy/paste segments of it as necessary in the console, then look at the results (while they are detached from the original vars)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best way is insert step:

```
.tap(console.log)
```

Other ways:

create mixin function

```
var debug = function (val) {
    console.log(val);
    return val;
}
_.mixin({'debug': debug})
```

and use it like

```
_(myArray)
    .debug()
    .filter({ keep: true })
    .debug()
    .uniq('id')
    .debug()
    .value()
```

or you can override lodash functions before it use like

```
_.filter = _.wrap(_.filter, function(func, val) {
    console.log(func(val));
    return func(val);
});
```