# Debug array method chain intermediate result in pure modern javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to see the array's state in the middle of a method chain:

```
arr.filter(...)
   .flatMap(...)
   .map(...)
   .sort()  // fyi, sort returns the sorted array
   // say I want to see the array content at this point
   .map(...)
   .slice(0, 10)
```

I can achieve this by using `tap()` function in underscorejs as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40624547/2649611). But I want to do this without using any library.

I have skimmed through [Array prototype functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) and it does not seem to have a function similar to `tap` function. Any workaround?

Comment: you'd have to write your own, or use the debugger. here is a quick mockup `Array.prototype.log = (...args) => ( console.log(this, args), this );`

Comment: If `arr` is relatively small, you can just add `.foreach(item => console.log(item))` to any point in the chain and see each array item on a new line in the console.

Comment: @A.Lamansky `.forEach` returns `undefined` though, it'd be not chain-able after `.forEach`.

Comment: @cakraww You're right, I had overlooked that detail but it does make `forEach` useless in this context. However, at the expense of slightly more code, you could use `.map` with an explicit return to achieve the same effect: `.map(item => {console.log(item); return item});`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just write one yourself:

```
// Be careful when overriding the default prototype, it might cause other code to fail or is a performance nightmare
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "log", {
  enumerable: false, // < make sure it doesnt suddenly appear somewhere (defaults to false though)
  value(name) {
    console.log(name, this);
    return this; // < enable chaining
  },
});

[1, 2, 3].filter(it => it > 1).log("after filtering");
```

If you want to log automatically, you could write a chainable wrapper:

```
const logChain = (arr) => ({
  log() {
   console.log(arr);
   return this;
  },
  result() { return arr; },
  map(cb, context) { 
    return logChain(arr.map(cb, context)).log();
  },
  // filter reduce etc.
});

logChain([1, 2, 3])
  .map(it => it + 1) // logs [2, 3, 4]
  .result() // unwrap
```

Or, if you want to achieve this with the most minimal code, just do:

```
const log = (...mutations) => arr => mutations.reduce((prev, op) => (it => (console.log(it), it))(op(prev)), arr);

log(
 it => it.map(n => n + 1),
 it => it.filter(it => it > 2)
)([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Comment: The first one is what I'm looking for! For more generalized `tap`-like function it'd be:
`Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "tap", { value(f) { f(this); return this; }});` and use it like `[1, 2, 3].tap(console.log).filter(it => it%2 == 1)`